# Service broker error when adding Single Sign On service

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

In Bluemix, when I try to add the Single Sign On service to a Java app, I get this error:

```
Service broker error: {"description"=>"CTJSO0015E The service instance with ID \"XXXXXXXXXX\" must be configured before the operation can be performed."}
```

The key parts of the error message are:

```
Service broker error ...
CTJSO0015E The service instance ...
must be configured before the operation can be performed.
```

My app is a new, empty Java runtime. The service instance gets created but doesn't get bound to the app. When I try to bind the service myself, I get the same error.

How do I get around this problem and bind the SSO service to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other Bluemix services, the Single Sign On service must be configured before it can be bound to an app. That process is explained in [Single Sign On/Configuring the service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index-gentopic1.html).

As the docs explain, you must create the service unbound (not bound to an app), configure it, then you can bind the configured service instance to the application.

This is also explained here: [Service Broken error While adding Single Sign On service](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/185168/while-creating-singlesingon-service-we-get-this-er.html).